# Pricing on google calendar API quota increase

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

My google calendar usage already exceeded the "Queries per minute" quota, which is 10,000. And my application hits 20,000 requests per minute for the moment, so I'm expecting to increase the quota to 200,000. When I tried to do it I was asked to create a billing account, which I'm going to do, but I need to know the pricing before that.

[image]

Despite my effort I was unable to find the exact information on pricing. Please help me understand the pricing involved with increasing the quotas of google calendar API.

*To give more information about the application, this is a backup application where we backup all the Google workspace data including the calendar events using service accounts. So all the payment for calendar service will be done by my company.*

Thank you.

Comment: The key question here is _who_ is paying for the calendar service. I mean, is it for a Google Workspace (Gsuite) user that connects to calendard.google.com/a/domain or for a general user? If it is for a Gsuite/Workspace it is included in the per-user monthly cost. If not, i am not sure what happens when you hit 1M calls.

Comment: Hi Iñigo, thanks your for replying. This is for Google Workspace users. I actually edited the question with more information about our application. So with your explanation we don't need do any payment? Them I'm not sure why we need to create an billing account for that!!

Comment: There are two items. The Payments account which pays for your services and the Billing Accounts which are track usage and billing. You already have a Payments account. You need to set up a Billing Account for Google Sheets to track usage. Since you are using Workspace, I would set up a Google Cloud Organization and move your project into the ORG so that the project and Workplace are working together. I am not sure about the API pricing; I would contact Google Cloud Billing support once you have the ORG setup with Billing enabled.